# Can I use a custom (Frame)Ticks specification to define the PlotRange?

Tags: plotting

The documentation for `Ticks` and `FrameTicks` shows how one can define a function for custom ticks or frame ticks, for example:

```
niceTicks[min_, max_, n_: 7] := FindDivisions[{min, max}, n]
```

After creating some example data

```
fakedata1 = FoldList[0.99 #1 + #2 &, 1., 
   RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], {100}]];
```

We can see that `FrameTicks` specifications will allow for functions, and will automatically pass the minimum and maximum of the data set as arguments.

```
ListLinePlot[fakedata1, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> All, PlotRangePadding -> 0, 
 FrameTicks -> {{niceTicks, None}, {Automatic, None}}]
```

[image]

Similarly one could use:

```
ListLinePlot[fakedata1, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> All, PlotRangePadding -> 0, 
 FrameTicks -> {{niceTicks[##, 10] &, None}, {Automatic, None}}]
```

[image]

As an aside, when using data points specified in terms of ${x,y}$ coordinates, as in `DateListPlot` and related functions, the `FrameTicks` specification will correctly pass the minimum and maximum *of the x or y coordinates as appropriate*, which is pretty cool.

My question is how one can link the `PlotRange` of the plot to the ticks determined by such a custom function. In this particular instance, the `FindDivisions` function called by `niceTicks` ranges from -2 to 10, but the plot only takes up as much space as the data require, plus any `PlotRangePadding`.

```
niceTicks[Min@fakedata1, Max@fakedata1]
(* {-2, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10}  *)
```

If I want the plot to have ticks effectively at the very top and bottom of the frame like this, using all the ticks output by my `niceTicks` function, I need to specify the PlotRange explicitly using the same `niceTicks` function:

```
ListLinePlot[fakedata1, Frame -> True, 
 PlotRange -> niceTicks[Min@fakedata1, Max@fakedata1][[{1, -1}]], 
 PlotRangePadding -> 0,  FrameTicks -> {{niceTicks, None}, {Automatic, None}}]
```

[image]

I'm sure that calling an auxiliary function twice like this doesn't add a lot of overhead, but it does require getting explicit minima and maxima from the data, which is a bit clunky when you consider multiple series, dated data for `DateListPlots` etc.

**Is there a way to pass the maximum and minimum tick values determined in the `Ticks` or `FrameTicks` option expression to the `PlotRange` option automatically?** It would be more elegant code with fewer special cases to code for. I'm building this into a suite of custom plotting functions, where a tick specification like the last picture shown is a requirement.

It would also be nice to pass the same tickmarks to `GridLines` somehow, so that `Automatic` gridlines automatically matched up with the specified ticks.

Comment: Incidentally, while researching this question I found an undocumented option of `FindDivisions`: `FindDivisions[{Min@fakedata1, Max@fakedata1}, 6, 
 Method -> "ExtendRange"]` gives `{-2, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10}`, as does `Method->Automatic`; any other setting for `Method` gives the inner divisions: `{0, 2, 4, 6, 8}`.

Comment: Given that the ticks function is apparently evaluated by the FrontEnd upon display of the plot, I'm not sure there is a way to handle this that does not double evaluate, therefore your own solution may be optimal.  You could always code a function to automate `PlotRange -> niceTicks[Min@fakedata1, Max@fakedata1][[{1, -1}]]` or you could generate the ticks outside of `Plot` entirely and feed both options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought something like what @Mr Wizard suggested might work but it seems that `PlotRange` is called earlier in the evaluation sequence. You can however match the `GridLines` ok:

```
niceTicks[min_, max_, n_: 7] := (yRange = {min, max}; 
  FindDivisions[{min, max}, n, Method -> "ExtendRange"])

Dynamic@ListLinePlot[fakedata1, 
  FrameTicks -> {{niceTicks[##, 3] &, None}, {Automatic, None}}, 
  GridLines -> {None, niceTicks[##, 3] &}, Frame -> True, 
  PlotRangePadding -> 0, PlotLabel -> yRange]
```

Unfortunately using `PlotRange->{Automatic,yRange}` doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your usage perhaps you can use a cheat like this:

```
niceTicks[min_, max_, n_: 7] := ($r = FindDivisions[{min, max}, n])

fakedata1 = 
  FoldList[0.99 #1 + #2 &, 1., 
   RandomReal[NormalDistribution[0, 1], {100}]];

Dynamic @ ListLinePlot[fakedata1, Frame -> True, PlotRangePadding -> 0, 
  FrameTicks -> {{niceTicks, None}, {Automatic, None}}, 
  PlotRange -> $r[[{1, -1}]]]
```

Hardly ideal given the global variable and double rendering, but at least it is concise.

Comment: **This doesn't work.**  It seems `niceTicks` is not evaluated again for new data (additional evaluations of the code block above).  I need to give this more thought.

Comment: This might work within a GUI-type interface for plotting, but I'm not sure I'd be game to use it generically in a package for general use.

Comment: @Verbeia indeed.  For a taste of the complexity behind FrameTicks (and plotting) take a look at this: `niceTicks[min_, max_, 
  n_: 7] := (Print[Stack[_]]; $r = FindDivisions[{min, max}, n])` (view Messages after plotting)

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers show, it turns out that this is not possible.

Using the same definition of `fakedata1` and `niceTicks`, the most concise code that would ensure the desired format would be:

```
With[{ticks = niceTicks[Min@fakedata1, Max@fakedata1]}, 
 ListLinePlot[fakedata1, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> ticks[[{1, -1}]],
   PlotRangePadding -> 0, GridLines -> {None, niceTicks}, 
  FrameTicks -> {{niceTicks, None}, {Automatic, None}}] ]
```

Or if you wanted to avoid the repeated call to `niceTicks` (and thus `FindDivisions`):

```
With[{ticks = niceTicks[Min@fakedata1, Max@fakedata1]}, 
 ListLinePlot[fakedata1, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> ticks[[{1, -1}]],
   PlotRangePadding -> 0, GridLines -> {None, ticks}, 
  FrameTicks -> {{ticks, None}, {Automatic, None}}] ]
```

Either gives the plot:

[image]

It would also be straightforward to refine the definition of `niceTicks`, taking care to narrow the first definition to match only numeric arguments, to ensure that passing it something like `niceTicks[data,4]` doesn't match the first definition and throw an error.

```
Clear[niceTicks];
niceTicks[min_?NumericQ, max_?NumericQ, n_: 7] := 
 FindDivisions[{min, max}, n]

niceTicks[x_?VectorQ, n_: 7] /; Length[x] > 3 := 
 FindDivisions[{Min@x, Max@x}, n]
```

Then this works, too:

```
With[{ticks = niceTicks[fakedata1]}, 
 ListLinePlot[fakedata1, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> ticks[[{1, -1}]],
   PlotRangePadding -> 0, GridLines -> {None, ticks}, 
  FrameTicks -> {{ticks, None}, {Automatic, None}}] ]
```