# Stop use of scientific notation when displaying FrameTicks

Tags: plotting

I have a dynamic graph which changes depending on the current selection from a drop down box. All selections from the drop down box give fine results except one. For the one selection it shows the `y` axis in scientific notation. I understand that this is due to the values being large but I don't want this to happen. I also can't specify the `y` axis values manually, I need to use the `FrameTicks->Automatic` functionality. Is there any way to stop the y-axis ticks from displaying in scientific notation?

[image]

Comment: Hi Lara! Please review your past questions. You never voted and never accepted an answer!

Comment: related question: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3436/66

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6851/formatting-ticks-and-frameticks-labels-with-a-function

Comment: belisarius, I dont know how to

Comment: @LaraJordan http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/faq#howtoask

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is definitely possible but you will need to define your own `FrameTicks` function. Fortunately you can do this with a defined auxiliary function.

You can use the information in [the answers to this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6108/8) to develop a custom tick function.

[This answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3739/8) provides some ideas about how to define a different format for your ticks.

You don't provide sample data, but here is an example which fits:

```
fakedata = RandomReal[{1*10^6, 3*10^9}, 10];

niceticks[min_, max_] := {#, NumberForm[#, DigitBlock -> 3], {0.02, 0}} & /@ 
  FindDivisions[{min, max}, 6]

ListLinePlot[fakedata, Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> {{niceticks, None}, {Automatic, None}}]
```

[image]

This approach will allow you to specify nice ticks for any data range, without knowing in advance what that range might be.

Given you have a very stretched `AspectRatio`, you will need a smaller number for the tick length: the number is a fraction of the plot width.

```
niceticks[min_, max_] := {#, NumberForm[#, DigitBlock -> 3], {0.01, 0}} & /@ 
  FindDivisions[{min, max}, 6]
```

Getting the x-ticks you want requires a similar approach, but the custom function can be simpler:

```
tickateveryinteger[min_, max_] := Range[Floor[min], Ceiling[max]]
```

Resulting in:

```
ListLinePlot[fakedata, Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}}, 
 FrameTicks -> {{niceticks, None}, {tickateveryinteger, None}}, 
 AspectRatio -> 1/5]
```

[image]

Comment: This is close, but when I use this how do I specify the range for the x axis ticks ? I need to see all the numbers and not just multiples of 2 on the x axis. Also, when I use this the tick marks on the y axis are stretched with my graph and look terrible.

Comment: Ok, I will edit for somethimg more precise. The issue with the tick length occurs because they are specified as fractions of the plot length.

Comment: I found out about the x axis problem, now it's just the problem of getting rid of the long ticks on the y axis.

Comment: Lara, see my edit

Comment: That works fine for the one graph but not too great when I choose one of the other drop down options and the graph displays something else. Is there not a way (perhaps with OptionInspector) to make sure Mathematica NEVER uses scientific notation anywhere at all?

Answer (score 3):

Does this work for you?

```
data = {#, # + 10^7} &@Table[2.5 10^8 + RandomInteger[10^8], {8}];

g = ListLinePlot[data, Axes -> False, 
   Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}}];
newticks = 
  AbsoluteOptions[g, 
    FrameTicks] /. {x_Real, x_, y__} :> {x, AccountingForm[x], y};

Show[g, newticks, AspectRatio -> 1/5]
```

The above changes all ticks to `AccountingForm`, which doesn't seem to matter for your example.  If you want just the `y` axis reformatted, then the following works:

```
newticks = 
  FrameTicks -> 
   MapAt[# /. {x_Real, x_, y__} :> {x, AccountingForm[x], y} &, 
    FrameTicks /. AbsoluteOptions[g, FrameTicks], 2];
Show[g, newticks, AspectRatio -> 1/5]
```

Note: The documentation indicates that `FrameTicks` should have the structure `{{left, right}, {bottom, top}}` but `AbsoluteOptions[g, FrameTicks]` returns `{bottom, left, top, right}`.  It seems to be an undocumented alternative.

[image: Mathematica graphics]