# How to change display of axis unit from radians to degrees in a plot

Tags: plotting

Is there a simple way, besides changing my function to use `Degree` as input, to display the x-axis in degrees in a plot of a function defined with its independent variable taking radians?

Comment: It does not get simpler than `Plot[f[x Degree],{x,-1,1}]` , and you can control exactly what is shown on the axis with the `Ticks` option of `Plot`. Theoretically you could do post-processing on the `Graphic` object but that seems to me to be overkill.

Comment: [not about `Degree` but duplicate imo](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8791/5478). Also [related](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6108/5478)

Answer (score 4):

```
f[range_List, divs_] := {# Pi/180, # Degree} & /@ FindDivisions[range 180/Pi, divs, 10]; 
plot[g_, range_]:= Plot[g[x], Evaluate@Join[{x}, range], Ticks-> {f[range, 10], Automatic}];
g = Sin;
plot[g, {0, 2 Pi}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Interesting, I din't know about `FindDivisions`. +1

Comment: @Murta The function doesn't work very well. The standard `Plot[]` automatic ticks are much more robust.

Comment: Is there a way to keep the nice sub-ticks when replacing the tick labels?